# How can I add meta data to text files by using "file-props.el"

Tags: files, bookmarks

I have a large number of text files with notes, and would like to add meta data (tags and comments) to each file, and display them when using dired. I am using windows 10, and emacs 25.0.93.1 (x86_w64-mingw32).

So I have installed file-props.el for this purpose, with file-props.el in my load path and  the following lines added to my init.el file:

```
(require 'file-props)
(file-props-load-properties)
(file-props-dired-activate-display)
(file-props-dired-setup-keybindings)
```

But when I try using the

`file-props-add-to-current-file` (when inside a text file) or

`file-props-dired-add-tags` (when having marked a text file in dired)

I get the following error message:

[image: Error message when using file-props commands]

Can anybody see whats wrong in my use of file-props? Thanks in advance for any help!

Are there other functions than file-props to add meta data to text files, when working in emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(The error message is telling you that something expected a list and instead was passed a symbol (that names the file).  Turn on `debug-on-error`, so you can see what the calling function is.  Then use `C-h f` for that function, to see how it should be called instead.)

---

I can't speak to [`file-props.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/file-props.el).  But I can speak to this:

> Are there other functions than file-props to add meta data to text files, when working in emacs?

[Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) provides tons of functions for adding [tags](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkTags) to and removing tags from [autofile bookmarks](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#AutofileBookmarks), which means  arbitrary files.

Tags are arbitrary names (strings), by default, but they can have associated [values](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#TagsAsAttributes) that are Lisp objects of any kind.  That is, a tag is metadata of the most general sort.

---

In addition to tags, a bookmark (and thus a file) can have an [annotation](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkAnnotations), which is a general textual description. The metadata of an annotation can be stored within the bookmark, or it can be *external* (which is useful when it is long).  An external annotation can be a file, a URL, or another bookmark.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When turning on 'debug-on-error', I get out 15 lines of lisp prose that I can't make any sense of.

Comment: The top of the backtrace that you get tells you what function raised the error, and what arguments it was passed. Use `C-h f` for that function, to find out what it expects as arguments. If you don't understand, post the top few lines of the backtrace in your question.

Comment: But anyway, I suggest you use Bookmark+. It has a lot more to offer, in the way of attaching metadata to files, than does `file-props.el`. Just a suggestion.

Comment: But file-props stores the meta data IN the text-file, right? While Bookmarks store the data outside the file. What I need is to see these meta data in a second column in dired, or a similar file list. I have 800 text files (with notes) that I would like to systematize. Making 800 bookmarks seems to be cumbersome.

Comment: No, `file-props.el` stores the metadata in the file that is the value of option `file-props-data-file`, which by default is `~/.emacs.d/file-props`. Bookmark+ stores the metadata for any given file in a bookmark, and bookmarks are stored in a bookmark file.  You can have any number of bookmark files.